Gem5 Arm SimpleAtomic CPU checkpoint interpretation
I am new to Gem5 and want to manually construct gem5 checkpoint from the information gained by gdb.
To this end, I try to understand gem5's checkpoint. However, even the integer register does not make sense. There are 336 elements in the gem5 checkpoint file, which is way more than the specification in
https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/0b2fa9900b3754787b4fd564937b8c145bcfbd5d/src/arch/arm/regs/int.hh
And this is also the gem5 version I am working on.
Any suggestion to move on?
I also refer to repo (https://github.com/PrincetonUniversity/QPoints) that attempts to construct gem5 checkpoint from the template. But it does not encounter the issue I mentioned. Perhaps, it is due to different version of gem5.
